# Is it possible to pass a type to an Angular component that can 'newed'?

Tags: angular, class, newable

I am developing a generic dropdown component. If the user enters a value not in the list, I want to return a new object *of the same type* in the itemSelected event. I need to preserve the methods as well as the properties - so just creating a generic object won't work. This needs to work even if the list is empty so it won't work to do something like Object.create(this.list[0]);

My work-around so far is to just pass a reference object, which I CAN use with Object.create but this seems lame.

The following snippet shows what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to do this or a better way to do what I want? Thanks - Jon

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generic-new',
  templateUrl: './generic-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-new.component.scss']
})
export class GenericNewComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  @Input() type:any 

  createNewType():any {
    // this is what I'm trying to do - but doesn't work
    return new this.type();
  }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Usually selected items are only strings, so is a newly entered value.  The work shouldn't be done by the select component but emitted to a listener. E. G. Use selects Person the event of person is sent and the listener does the work. We can't anticipate something not in the list right?

Comment: The component accepts a list of objects of any type. The user specifies a display value and a key. If the user enters a value not in the list, a new item is created with id = zero. For example, a list of cities - city_id, city_name. The user is allowed to add a city not in the list. So in this case I would want to create a new city object - but the new object should still have any methods in the city object. This component is the listener to another component that deals with the actual list of values. In any case - IF there is a way to make the snippet above work, this will solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Generics

```
class container<T> {
    id: T;
    key: T;
    displayValue: T;
    type : T;        
}
//allows you to control the type, here we are allowing any, but could be person, address etc.
let myContainer = new container<any>();
myContainer.id = 0;
myContainer.key = "UserEnteredKey";
myContainer.displayValue = "UserEnteredDisplayValue;
myContiner.type //allow access to anything or a specific class type.
```

Not using generics.

```
class container{
 id:number;
 key:number;
 displayValue:string;
 type:any;
}
let myContainer = new contaier();
myContainer.number = 10;
myContainer.key = "UserEnteredKey";
myContainer.displayValue = "User Entered Display Value";
myContainer.type = {key:myContainer.key, display: myContainer.displayValue, doSomething: function(){//do something here.}}
```

Note that any of the values above can be computed instead of being static, for example IDs are usually computed.

```
 @Input() type:container

  createNewType():any {
    // this is what I'm trying to do - but doesn't work
    return
     let myContainer = new container<any>();
     myContainer.id = this.getNextID();
     myContainer.key = "UserEnteredKey";
     myContainer.displayValue = "UserEnteredDisplayValue;
     myContiner.type //allow access to anything or a specific class type.
}
```

Your form will need to expose all the properties the user needs to change via binding to this cass model.